# "Error: Could Not create constraint or index. see previous errors" with nest js and AzureSql

Tags: azure, nestjs, azure-sql-database, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am trying to use TypeORM with NestJS to make a migration in AzureSQL but the query failed in alter table to create FK. Below are the entities and errors:

```
query failed: ALTER TABLE "procedure" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_f4621b8148f6622456a554adcc6" FOREIGN KEY ("patientId") REFERENCES "patient"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
error: QueryFailedError: Error: Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
[Nest] 15636  - 22/03/2024, 10:56:12   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (8)...
QueryFailedError: Error: Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
    at C:\Users\david\Documents\clinica-back\src\driver\sqlserver\SqlServerQueryRunner.ts:282:30
    at C:\Users\david\Documents\clinica-back\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:440:25
    at Request.userCallback (C:\Users\david\Documents\clinica-back\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:492:15)
    at Request.callback (C:\Users\david\Documents\clinica-back\node_modules\tedious\src\request.ts:379:14)
    at Parser.onEndOfMessage (C:\Users\david\Documents\clinica-back\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:3713:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:28)
    at Parser.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (C:\Users\david\Documents\clinica-back\node_modules\tedious\src\token\token-stream-parser.ts:30:12)
    at Readable.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
```

**Patient Entity**

```js
@Entity()
export class Patient{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column({type: 'varchar', length: 11, nullable: false, unique: true})
    cpf: string;
    
    @Column({type: 'varchar', length: 200, nullable: false})
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(()=> Procedure, procedure=>procedure.patient, { 
        nullable: false, 
        cascade: true, 
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'} )
    procedures: Procedure[]
}
```

**Procedure Entity**

```js
@Entity()
export class Procedure{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number
    
    @Column({type: 'varchar', nullable: false})
    name: string;
    
    @ManyToOne(()=>Patient, (patient)=> patient.procedures, 
    { nullable: false, onDelete: 'NO ACTION', onUpdate: 'NO ACTION'})
    patient: Patient;
}
```

one (patient) to many (procedures) relationship;

OBS: I tried the same context with MSSQL in a local machine and it works!

Comment: Your error states "See previous errors."; what were those previous errors?

Comment: This is the problema, the unique error is query failed when try create FK. But i dont see some issue in query